# php update status of post after 15 days of submission

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

I have a postdate and status column in mysql table. currently status of post is = 1. all i want to change the status = 0 after 15days submission of the post.
Any one there to help.

```
$todays = date('d-m-Y');
echo $todays;

mysql_query("UPDATE property SET status=1 WHERE expiredate > '".$todays."'");
//echo "record updated!";
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Use a cron-job to do that.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You want to change the status to 0, but your SQL call is changing it to 1??? Am I not reading your question clearly?

Comment: WHERE DATEDIFF($todays, postdate) >= 15

Comment: @DanielA.White Just wondering, you say it is vulnerable to sql injection, even though the value is being generated by the server with the date function?

Comment: @Pitchinnate its still a bad practice.

Comment: Bad practice because mysql_* is *deprecated* as of PHP 5.5.0. Not because of SQL injection in this particular case.

Comment: @DanielA.White, please don't confuse people here... It's apparent you haven't understood the whole problem of SQL injection. It was exactly this type of thinking that led to the brain-damaged `magic_gpc_quotes`...

Answer (score 4):

Your date is backwards. MySQL date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
$todays = date('d-m-Y');
```

should be

```
$todays = date('Y-m-d');
```

Plus a better way to do this is with pure SQL:

```
UPDATE property SET status=0 WHERE expiredate < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

Comment: john i've changed the structure to Y-m-d and put two dummy records in database. And tried sql query but it did'nt modified anything.

Comment: Which query did you use? Mine? Or yours?

Comment: $todays = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("update property set status=0 where expiredate < '".$todays."' ");

worked out i guess

Comment: just one more question.
how often i should run that query in my website where i get posts and automatically it update. in database connet file or in index? your advice is required :)

Answer (score 3):

This will be a combination of a cron script to run and a MySQL statement.

First, the cron entry would probably run once a day (this example is once a day at 1a.m.)

```
* * * 1 0 /path/to/script.php
```

Then, your PHP script would create a MySQL query (without the need for PHP variables) - using the assumed name of your table 'property'

```
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$db->query('update property set status=0 where status=1
            and expiredate < date_sub(now(), interval 15 day');
```

This will automatically take the current expiredate, subtract 15 days and use that for the calculation.  Additionally, it checks to make sure the status is 1 - so that it doesn't keep updating that field for tables that have already been updated.

Comment: Actually the `status = 1` in where clause is not needed. Mysql will update only rows, which have `status <> 0`. Mysql is a pretty clever girl ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the query periodically to set the status accordingly. You could have a script run every day at some hour which would run a query against the DB. If you have a Linux server take a look a cron jobs as this is what you're looking for.

Comment: actually i am getting date of post and putting status into 1. after 15 days i want to change the status into 0. no physically deleting record just changing its status